# Xamarin and Net Standard - How does the assemblies resolution work in that example

Tags: c#, compilation, .net-core, assemblies, .net-standard

This question is illustrated with that [sample on github](https://github.com/FrancoisM/AotTests/tree/SignalR_rc1_final). You can try it with branch SignalR_rc1_final.

It's a solution with a .Net Standard library (Xamarin Forms) and an iOS app.
In the library, I reference the nuget package [AspNetCore Signalr Client](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client/1.0.0-rc1-final)

The iOS project doesn't build with linking. There is an error saying:

> Failed to resolve "System.Buffers.IBufferWriter`1" reference from "System.Memory, Version=4.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51"

My question is **not** about signalr or getting ride of the error as such. There is already a ticket open in their [github repo](https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR/issues/1886#issuecomment-387177490).

What I'd like to understand is why the compiler tries to resolve `System.Buffers.IBufferWriter` that it found in `System.Memory, Version=4.0.1.0` (confirmed [here](https://apisof.net/catalog/System.Buffers.IBufferWriter%3CT%3E))? Indeed, `System.Memory` is reference in `SignalR` but the version `4.5.0-rc1` is.

[image]

So where does the reference to `System.Memory, Version=4.0.1.0` comes from in the first place? What resolution mechanism happens that is hidden to me and how can I better follow and understand it?

UPDATE

I start to understand what's going on. I'll post an answer once I figure it out totally if no one does it first.

The SignalR library target both `netstandard2.0` and `netcore2.1`. `System.Memory version 4.0.1.0` is within the Net Core 2.1 runtime and hence is not a separated nuget package. This is why I don't see it under the nuget dependency tree in the image.

So somewhere SignalR uses it when it compiles for `netcore2.1`. What I still don't understand and how can the `netstandard2.0` version (that Xamarin consumes) compiles fine with a reference to an assemblies that it "doesn't know" about.